# The cursor Icon doesn't change after I set allowDragging to false in syncfusion/ej2-angular-layouts

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

So I have made an editable dashboard with syncfusion/ej2-angular-layouts and have bind the allowDragging property to a variable which I make it to true on clicking on 'Edit Dashboard' button. When I click on 'Save' button it's set to false. So everything works fine but after making the allowDragging property to false again the cursor icon still remains the same as in the edit mode.
Is there a way to bring back the cursor to normal as it was before.

html file

```html
<div class="control-section">
    <ejs-dashboardlayout id='defaultLayout' #defaultLayout [columns]='columns' [cellSpacing]='cellSpacing' [panels]='panels' 
    [allowDragging]='allowDragging'>
    </ejs-dashboardlayout>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="editOn()">Edit Dashboard</button>
  <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

ts file

```js
allowDragging = false;

editOn(){
  this.allowDragging = true;
}

save(){
  this.allowDragging = false;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code samples.

Comment: Added just now. My code looks similar to the above code

Answer (score 0):

We were unable to reproduce your reported problem in the Syncfusion Angular Dashboard Layout component with your provided details. When we set the false value for allowDragging property the drag icon will not be shown. We have prepared a sample for your convenience, please refer to the below link for the sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dashboard-dragging?file=app.component.ts

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started/

API reference: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/dashboard-layout/

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/dashboard-layout/analytics-dashboard

If the issue still persists, please share some additional details it will help us provide you the prompt solution.

1. Have you added any other components inside of dashboard? if yes, share the details.
2. If facing any console error, share the screenshots.
3. If possible, please replicate your issue with the shared sample.
4. Share the screen recorded video.

Comment: Yes there are components loaded on the dashboard. The user has ability to add components. So the components the user chose are added. The information of what components the user wants is stored on the database. So every time the dashboard loads the chosen components are loaded. Thanks for the detailed reply, I'll try to replicate the issue and also share a video link in some time. Thanks again !!

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but I was not able to replicate the error. Here is a video link- https://youtu.be/Qvr0Y33xfeU